# encounter error 'str' object has no attribute 'log' when perform np.log()

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, logarithm

after I set date to date object and make it index, when I use np.log(), i got the error message:
AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'log'
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable log method
my input value is a series of data, which shouldn't be a problem
[python codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjhWA.jpg)

Comment: You have an object dtype array with strings (and may other stuff)

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why are you using `log` with dates?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried taking the values and placing them in an array before applying the log?

```
np.log(np.array(ts_data.values))
```